# vscode python extension displayDiscoverStatus [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

Code gives me the following errors when pytest performs test discovery. I'm using a virtual environment (Pipenv) and have the environment activated in vscode. The error occurred some time after i upgraded to vscode Juli version 2020. I have tried removing and purging code with dpkg, and deleted the extensions located in `~/.vscode/extensions`. After that, I installed the June version where i previously had no errors, but the error still occurs.

Python test log:

```
python /home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /home/christian/Documents/source/personalprojects/portfolioapp/services/activity-service -s --cache-clear tests
Test Discovery failed: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Python log:

```
> ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/activity-service-aBZdkeOh/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir ~/Documents/source/personalprojects/portfolioapp/services/activity-service -s --cache-clear tests
cwd: ~/Documents/source/personalprojects/portfolioapp/services/activity-service
Error 2020-08-16 17:51:49: Failed to parse discovered Test [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:39:327177
    at f.exec (/home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:48:935503)
    at async f.discoverTests (/home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:48:934976)] {
  stdout: ''
}
Error 2020-08-16 17:51:49: Python Extension: displayDiscoverStatus [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:39:327177
    at f.exec (/home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:48:935503)
    at async f.discoverTests (/home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/out/client/extension.js:48:934976)] {
  stdout: ''
}
```

If I run pytest inside the virtual env, The test runs succesfully without errors - so it seems have something to do with the python extension.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates the output of the pytest discover test command is not conformed to JSON regulation.

And you said the pytest works well in the terminal. So could you run the command in the Python test log directly in the terminal, and to check the outputs of this command?

the command:

```
python /home/christian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.101144/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /home/christian/Documents/source/personalprojects/portfolioapp/services/activity-service -s --cache-clear tests
```

If the outputs of this command really does not comply with JSON regulation that means the problem was caused by the pytest package, you need to fix the pytest package you are using.

If the outputs comply with the JSON regulation that means the problem was caused by the Python extension or the VSCode, as you have deleted the extension be located at ~/.vscode/extensions and reinstall the VSCode but the error still exists, so could you delete the project cache which under: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage(in windows)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up moving the files to a new folder to fix the error, before I received your response, but i'll keep this in mind if the error comes up again.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Adapting the `run_adapter.py` command above to my use case returns an empty string. The logs in vscode also complain about an empty string `stdout: ''`

Comment: Just adding a comment that if you print/log anything (I assume to STDOUT) during module unload, it might cause a similar `SyntaxError` issue as it will be adding non-JSON parseable text.